# Filtrar mensualmente en Firestore

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo registros en la bd de Firestore y cada uno tiene varias fechas, estas fechas están guardadas como String con el formato "yyyy/MM/dd". Hasta ahora tengo hecho que pasando la fecha que yo quiera en el mismo formato en el que esta me devuelva todos los registros con esa fecha, con esta linea:

```
dc.getDocument().getReference().collection("partidos").whereEqualTo("fecha", fechaEscogida)
```

Pues bien, lo que me gustaría saber es si hay alguna forma de que me devuelva los registros mensualmente, es decir, pasando la fechaEscogida (o la parte solo del mes "??/MM/??") al igual que arriba y que compare la parte del mes con las fechas guardadas en la bd devolviendo así todos los registros de ese mismo mes.

Se que Firestore posee herramienta de rangos con las fechas pero en mi bd las fechas no están en formato Timestamp si no que, como digo, están en String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el formato es estrictamente "yyyy/MM/dd" y no quieres/puedes cambiar eso en tu base de datos (que sería lo ideal), puedes de igual manera usar operadores de mayor y menor qué con strings. Mira este ejemplo:

```js
const principio = "2020/07/01";
const final = "2020/07/31";

function test(fecha){
  if( (fecha >= principio) && (fecha <= final)) {
    console.log(`La fecha ${fecha} esta dentro del rango: [${principio} - ${final}]`)
  }else{
    console.log(`La fecha ${fecha} NO esta dentro del rango: [${principio} - ${final}]`)
  }
}

test("2020/06/30");
test("2020/07/20");
test("2020/08/30");
```

Eventualmente tu código sería algo como:

```
const principio = "2020/07/01"
const final = "2020/07/31"

dc.getDocument().getReference().collection("partidos")
    .where('fecha', '>=', principio)
    .where('fecha', '<=', final)
```

Espero que esto sea de ayuda, suerte en tu programación!

Answer (score 0):

Si, se puede hacer, tene en cuenta que en Firestore almacenas un timestamp de tipo Date (depende el modelo de como lo mandas) y no un timestamp INT , para hacer lo que queres hacemos lo siguiente

```
val unMes = (Date().time - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) * 30
dc.getDocument().getReference().collection("partidos").whereLessThan("fecha", Date(unMes))
```

Esta querie te va a traer todos los documentos cuyo tiempo haya pasado mas de un mes desde el momento que solicitas esta querie, alternativamente podes cambiar el unMes a la fecha que vos quieras y podes filtrar de esta forma los documentos que necesites

El ejemplo esta en kotlin pero es lo mismo para java

si queres de una fecha especifica solo usas `whereEqualTo` y cambias la fecha de `unMes` a la que vos quieras